# .sbt redefining test task

Tags: scala, sbt

For my specific reason, I'd like to override `test` task to run not all tests, but to behave like `test-only TopTestSuiteName param1 param2`. Is it possible?

I tried to go through documentation on tasks and examples, but still far from understanding what is possible and what's not.

Or maybe I could create custom task and somehow use existing `test-only` functionality? I feel it is reasonable but completely cannot understand - where do I start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you leave `test` alone and add a custom thing instead.

How about an alias? You could just add this to your `.sbt` definition:

```
addCommandAlias("myTest", "testOnly TopTestSuiteName -- param1 param2")
```

But if you actually need `myTest` to be a task (for example if you want another task to depend on it), then here's code (in `.sbt` format for sbt 0.13) for reusing `testOnly` functionality in a custom task:

```
val myTest = taskKey[Unit]("call testOnly with some special args")

myTest in Test :=
  (testOnly in Test).toTask(" TopTestSuiteName -- param1 param2").value
```

Comment: I left out `param1 param2` in my answer because I can't tell what your intended meaning there is. Who or what are you trying to pass those parameters to, exactly...?

Comment: In `test-only` those are "command-line" test arguments (I use ScalaTests's ConfigMap to pass database access credentials to TestSuites)

Comment: I've edited my answer on the assumption what you meant was `testOnly Foo -- param1 param2`. `testOnly` uses `--` to separate class names from parameters that are passed through to the test framework.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. A couple of notes for future thought: `addCommandAlias` creates top level alias (I have multiproject, and it is not desired). `toTask` needs `sbt >= 0.13.1`.